# How to display additional fileds I've added to a page - the way I want them?

Tags: theming, nodes, entities

I've added some additional fields to the content type - Page. But now when the page is rendered it displays all of them as well - just lists them at the bottom of the content. But that's not what I want - I do not want them to display at all, I just want to use them elsewhere in PHP code. There should probably be a hook for this, but I still just can't get my head around the whole thing. Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding additional fields is easy, just notice **Display Fields** tab at the **Manage Fields** page for the specified content type (page in this case). There you can easily exclude additional fields from being automatically appended to the $content.

In order to show fields the way you want them use **themename_preprocess_page** hook and check $vars['node'] object for the particular fields.

Answer (score 2):

I found that often you need a lot more control than just using render($content) gives you.  Maybe you want fields in a different order, or wrapped specifically in DIVs or other tags. Personally I hated letting Drupal just dump out the entire array in a TPL file.

I'm in the middle of a huge Drupal project and find myself often pulling items out of the content array individually:

```
print $content->field_name
```

Answer (score 1):

As jayarjo says, you want to use the *Display Fields* tab.

One caveat here is the difference between *Display Fields* and the *Exclude* option.

If you set a field to **not** display, the HTML won't be generated, but the data will still be available for other uses.

If you instead check the *Exclude* option, the field won't be passed to your theme at all: no HTML, no data.